# Printing list by element with mapping via a list of lists

Tags: python

I have a table represented in the form of a list of list:

```
table = [[1, 9695],[2, 4755],[6,447]]
```

and another list containing the values of the second column of the table above where the numbers are in ascending order.

```
lst = [447,4755,9695]
```

I'm trying to print the values in lst since it's already in ascending order but instead of just printing out the values as such:

```
447
4755
9695
```

i want to also have the values at the first column of the table printed together with it:

```
No: 6  Total distance travelled: 447
No: 2  Total distance travelled: 4755
No: 1  Total distance travelled: 9695
```

I've tried something like:

```
n = len(lst)
for i in range(n):
    if table[i][1] == lst[i]:    
        print("No: " + str(table[i][0]) + " " + "Total distance  
        travelled: " + str(lst[i]))
```

but it's only printing out certain values but not all of them. I would appreciate some help on this. **Note that I'm not advised to use any built in functions such as lambda** and so on but just something similar as what i've wrote.

Comment: `lambda` is not a builtin function, it's a way to create your own functions. That requirement is like saying "don't use any built in functions such as `for` or `=`".  If your teacher actually said this, they don't understand Python well enough to teach it. If your teacher actually told you something more sensible, then you need to pay more attention.

Comment: Are you allowed to convert the `table` to a dictionary? (I suppose not; but if you *can*, the answer is trivial.)

Comment: @Maxxx, `len`, `range` are built-ins

Comment: Also, as posted, the code won't even compile; there's a `SyntaxError` in your print statement. Please give us a real, working example of your error. (See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root problem you're asking about here is this:

```
if table[i][1] == lst[i]:
```

You're not checking *every* table entry, you're just checking whichever one happens to have the same index as the current list entry. So, for `447` you're only checking whether `[1, 9695]` matches `447`, which it doesn't.

If you really want to do things this way, you need another loop:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if table[j][1] == lst[i]:
```

There are a lot of ways to improve this—just use `for entry in lst:` instead of `for i in range(n)` and then `lst[i]`, and replace `table` with a `dict` instead of a `list`, and so on.

Also, you need to fix at least one other bug in your code.

But this will make the part you're asking about work, in a way you can hopefully understand.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 'temporary' list containing the `table[n][1]` values, and use this with `index` to look up the `lst` values.

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print ('No %d Distance %4d' % (table[[x[1] for x in table].index(lst[i])][0], table[[x[1] for x in table].index(lst[i])][1]))
```

Output:

```
No 6 Distance  447
No 2 Distance 4755
No 1 Distance 9695
```

Not so efficient because it recreates the re-sorted list *twice* for each line, but perhaps you are allowed to create a temporary list to store it in:

```
l = [x[1] for x in table]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    print ('No %d distance %4d' % (table[l.index(lst[i])][0],table[l.index(lst[i])][1]))
```

(Same output.)

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary is one solution:

```
table = [[1, 9695],[2, 4755],[6,447]]
lst = [447,4755,9695]

d = {v: k for k, v in table}

for i in lst:
    print('No: {0}  Total distance travelled: {1}'.format(d[i], i))

# No: 6  Total distance travelled: 447
# No: 2  Total distance travelled: 4755
# No: 1  Total distance travelled: 9695
```

Answer (score 0):

Either a dictionary or a just simply sort the list:

```
table = [[1, 9695],[2, 4755],[6,447]]
lst = [447,4755,9695]

table_sorted = sorted(table, key=lambda alist: alist[1])
for x in table_sorted:
    print('{0} ... {1}'.format(x[0], x[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the list. You can just use [itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to sort the table as you want it.

```
from operator import itemgetter

table = [[1, 9695],[2, 4755],[6,447]]

sorted_list = sorted(table, key=itemgetter(1))
print(sorted_list)
```

Output:

```
[[6, 447], [2, 4755], [1, 9695]]
```

The simply this:

```
for item in sorted_list:
    print("No: " + str(item[0]) + " Total distance travelled: " + str(item[1]))
```

Output:

```
No: 6 Total distance travelled: 447
No: 2 Total distance travelled: 4755
No: 1 Total distance travelled: 9695
```